# Mosquitto MQTT broker with TLS - client connection errors

Tags: ubuntu, mqtt, lets-encrypt, mosquitto

I have a Ubuntu server with Mosquitto.
I'm using Lets Encrypt to create certificates for it following the instructions at: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-the-mosquitto-mqtt-messaging-broker-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart

My config file looke like this:

```
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

allow_anonymous true
password_file /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto_users
max_inflight_messages 0

#default listener
listener 1883
protocol mqtt

listener 8883
certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mqtt.spider-e.com/cert.pem
cafile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mqtt.spider-e.com/chain.pem
keyfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mqtt.spider-e.com/privkey.pem


listener 9001
protocol websockets
certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mqtt.spider-e.com/cert.pem
cafile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mqtt.spider-e.com/chain.pem
keyfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mqtt.spider-e.com/privkey.pem
```

So far so good.
On the same machine, from a command line I'm testing the setup by using:

> mosquitto_pub -h mqtt.spider-e.com -t 'testing' -m "hello" -p 8883 --capath /etc/letsencrypt/live/mqtt.spider-e.com/

But I get:

> "Error: A TLS error occurred."

And at that point, the mosquitto log file has:

```
1626191477: New connection from 87.117.234.67 on port 8883.
1626191477: OpenSSL Error: error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca
1626191477: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
1626191478: New connection from 87.117.234.67 on port 8883.
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `--capath` to work you must run `openssl rehash <path to capath>` every time a certificate is added or removed from the directory.

You can use `--cafile` instead to point directly to the CA certificates.